# Route the Application based on Drop down Selection in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am implementing the single page application using Angualr2.It should be capable to handle the multiple user roles in the one application.Assume that i have two user roles **Admin** and **Employee** and logged in user should be able to switch between those roles by selecting top drop down.Also each role contains different views in component.
[image]

As in the above picture by default user has been assigned to **Admin** role.according to the drop down selection left side menu route URL will be changed something like below.

```
dropDown Value= Admin
Home url =/home/admin
Reports url=reports/admin

if drop down value Employee
dropDown Value= Employee
Home url =/home/employee
Reports url=reports/employee
```

**Note:** This work perfectly fine with current implementation.But there is a issue if i re route to same url. eg: let say currently drop down selection is **Admin** and in a **Home view** and within same view if i change drop down value into Employee and re click the Home menu it wont update the **home view** data even i used **RoleService**.But url changed as expected.

**(1) My first question is that How can i update the View again any angaulr life cycle hook to implement my logic?**

**(2) My second question is that how can i get current URL in angaulr and update the url. eg: drop down selection is **Admin** and in the **Home view** then within same view change the drop down value into Employee and as a result url should change from **/home/admin** to **/home/employee** so how can i append only param value?**

**Left Menu HTML**

```
<a (click)="appNavigateTo('/home')">
          <span>Home</span>
 </a>
<a (click)="appNavigateTo('/reports')">
          <span>Reports</span>
 </a>
```

**MenuComponent.tc**

```
appNavigateTo(url: any) {
    this.router.navigate([url, this._roleService.getCurrentlyLoggedInRole()]);
  }
```

**Route.ts**

```
{ path: 'home/:role',         component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'report/:role',         component: ReportComponent},
```

**DropdownComponent.ts**

```
export class DropdownComponent{

    construtor ( private _roleService : RoleService){}
    getSelectedRole( event: any ) {
        this._roleService.setCurrentlyLoggedInRole(event.target.value);
    }

}
```

**RoleService.ts**

```
static LOGGED_IN_ROLE= ROLE.ADMIN;
  /* Return the currently logged in role*/
  public getCurrentlyLoggedInRole(): String {
    return RoleService.LOGGED_IN_ROLE;
  }
  /*Set currently logged in role*/
  public setCurrentlyLoggedInRole(role: string): void {
    RoleService.LOGGED_IN_ROLE = role;
  }
```

Please let me know how to overcome above mentioned questions. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can update the view by subscribing to the activatedRoute observable in your ngOnInit lifecycle hook. This allows for you

   ```
   ngOnInit(){
       this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
           // this is ran everytime the url changes
           // do whatever you need to update the view
       }
   }
   ```

https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

2. I am a bit confused by #2. I think it might be worth it to look into the route snapshot https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#members